# How to override @types from package that are a completely different type?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to override the `Func` type in Mocha.

It's authored as:

```
type Func = (this: Context, done: Done) => void;
```

I want to change it to a function with overloads.

```
import * as M from "mocha";
declare global {
  namespace Mocha {
    export interface Func {
      (this: M.Context): void;
      (this: M.Context, done: M.Done): void;
      (this: M.Context, done?: M.Done): void;
    }
  }
}
```

I get this error:

```
Duplicate identifier 'Func'.ts(2300)
index.d.ts(2178, 10): 'Func' was also declared here.
```

Its pretty easy to extend an interface, but I find it impossible to change a type completely in this case `type` to `interface`.

Comment: Why do you want to switch it to an interface? Couldn't you make it a union type with those three Func signatures?

Comment: @katamaster818 in this case I need the type to include overloads, I believe I can do that with an interface, but this same error occurs if you try to replace or an a union to `type Func` as well.